# SQLalchemy not returning BLOB on querying multiple records

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
    if current_blog.pin:
        pin_post = post.query.get(current_blog.pin)
        pin_post.text = pin_post.text.decode("utf-8")
    else:
        pin_post = False

    feed = post.query.filter_by(author=author_id).order_by(post.timestamp.desc()).all()
    # Not decoding feed works fine but the code to decode as follows:
    #for p in feed:
    #    print(p.text)
    #    p.text = p.text.decode("utf-8")
```

Using Flask-SQLalchemy, I have a MySQL table `post` with `post.text` column of type `BLOB`. I store UTF-8 strings by encoding it using `str.encode()`in this. When querying a single record, it returns a blob that I need to decode else it returns error `cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`. But when querying multiple records, it returns a str such that trying decoding it return error `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`. What exactly is causing this difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was with querying and decoding the same post twice.

```
if pin_post in feed:
    feed.remove(pin_post)
```

This solved the issue.